# flutter images are not found

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using flutter to create an app. The pictures I needed I put into /assets/images and added the following lines in pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Everything worked as expected. But after a while, the pictures became too many and I created a folder like bg and shapes, modified pubspec.yaml to

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/bg/
    - assets/images/shapes/
```

And it was still working until a few days later flutter started to give me that message that one single picture could not be found. Then I moved that single image back to /assets/images/ and was fine. Another few days later that happened again and so forth until all the images were back in assets/images/

Could somebody please explain how this works exactly and what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code?, Are your clean the project after changes the resources ?

Comment: haven't I already shared my code? .. :) is there anything else of importance. but I'm indeed not sure about the cleaning so I'll take that into consideration in the future. thx for that

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how it looks like in one of my projects:

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - assets/ezgif-test.gif
  - assets/djung.png
  - assets/player-bg.png
  - assets/logo-400-white.png
  - assets/onboarding0.png
  - assets/onboarding1.png
  - assets/onboarding2.png
```

In this example we could also say `assets/whateverfoldername/yourfilre.jpg`

The important thing with this (and I did it wrong alot by accident) is the right distance between the left corner and the the asset lines. As you can see above the flutter part isnt on the same vertical position (or hirarchy) as the asset lines. If you are one more tab inside or outside, the `pubspec yaml` cant read your asset lines anymore. This part is really sensitive and you have to make sure the distances are fine.

Also you have to call the files one by one with the full name like you can see in my example. This is how I have learned it. If you then place the files in the exact path, you should be able to call the files without problems.

Comment: so I really do have to add all the image names there? its a very lot.. or it's going to be at least